# Generate balanced Parenthesis

Tags: c++, recursion

The tried below logic to generate the possible set of balanced parenthesis. but each possible output is getting printed twice.

```
void balanced_parenthesis(vector<string>& out_vec,string out_str,int is_open,int is_close)
{
    
    if(is_open == 0 && is_close == 0)
    {
        cout<<out_str<<endl;
        out_vec.push_back(out_str);
        return;
    }
    
    if(is_open != 0)
    {
       
        out_str += '(';
        is_open = is_open-1;
        balanced_parenthesis(out_vec,out_str,is_open,is_close);
        
    }
    
    if( is_close > is_open)
    {
        
        out_str += ')';
        is_close = is_close-1;
        balanced_parenthesis(out_vec,out_str,is_open,is_close);
    }
  
}
```

however by decrementing is_close and is_open variables in the function call prints the output exactly once.

```
void balanced_parenthesis(vector<string>& out_vec,string out_str,int is_open,int is_close)
{
    
    if(is_open == 0 && is_close == 0)
    {
        cout<<out_str<<endl;
        out_vec.push_back(out_str);
        return;
    }
    
    if(is_open != 0)
    {
       
        out_str += '(';
        balanced_parenthesis(out_vec,out_str,is_open,is_close);
        
    }
    
    if( is_close > is_open)
    {
        out_str += ')';
        balanced_parenthesis(out_vec,out_str,is_open,is_close-1);
    }
  
}
```

Could anyone explain me behaviour of the first code ?

Comment: Could you please post a [mre] along with some examples of the expected behavior?

Comment: Consider the case when `is_close == is_open`, and both are non-zero, when you enter the function. Think about whether `is_close > is_open` will be true or not in both implementations.